# Meaning of ADDRESS formula arguments

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have to convert this function into VBA and I couldn't understand what the second numbers after the comma inside the `ADDRESS()` meant. The function is used to calculate time difference between two systems. I know that `ADDRESS()` can get optional parameters of numbers from 1 to 4, but I don't think this isn't the case here. Can you please help me understand it?

```
IF(Z44<>"N/R",((INDIRECT(ADDRESS(Y44,1))-INDIRECT(ADDRESS(Z44,1)))*86400)+((INDIRECT(ADDRESS(Y44,6))-INDIRECT(ADDRESS(Z44,6)))*86400),"N/R")
```

Comment: ```ADDRESS``` just transforms (row_number, column_number) from R1C1. So ```ADDRESS(2,4)``` is the cell "D2", ```ADDRESS(3,5)``` is the cell "E3", etc.

Comment: I know what ADDRESS() does, but in the given example columns are written as letters. So I couldn't understand what the other half means.

Comment: ```ADDRESS``` will only give a non-error return for number values on both sides of the comma. So presumably, the cells Y44 and Z44 have numbers in them that come from a formula themselves. Probably not how I would set it up, but impossible to know for sure

Comment: You are right, those cells have numbers in them that change in every row, so they set it up like that. What I don't understand are those numbers after the comma. The thing is when I calculate the formula without those numbers, I get a similar result but not the same. So I need to understand what they do.

Comment: Isn't the number after the comma just the column reference? So column "A" in the first two and column "F" in the next two?

Comment: Didn't you find some time to check the answer I posted? If checked, still something unclear?

Comment: It is all clear thanks to you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next VBA code, able to convert the formula you show. Select a cell and run the code. It will return exactly what the formula does:

```
Sub testVBAFromFormula()
  '=IF(Z44<>"N/R",((INDIRECT(ADDRESS(Y44,1))-INDIRECT(ADDRESS(Z44,1)))*86400)+((INDIRECT(ADDRESS(Y44,6))-INDIRECT(ADDRESS(Z44,6)))*86400),"N/R")
  Dim sh As Worksheet, cel As Range
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  Set cel = ActiveCell

    If sh.Range("Z44").Value <> "N/R" Then
        cel.Value = (sh.Range("A" & sh.Range("Y44").Value).Value - sh.Range("A" & sh.Range("Z44").Value).Value) * 86400 + _
                    (sh.Range("F" & sh.Range("Y44").Value).Value - sh.Range("F" & sh.Range("Z44").Value).Value) * 86400
    Else
        cel.Value = "N/R"
    End If
End Sub
```

If you split the formula in small pieces you can better understand what happens:

`"=ADDRESS(Y44,1)"` returns "A" & the number in "Y44", let us imagine 23. "A" is the first column, defined by the second parameter `1`.

`"=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(Y44,1))"` returns **the value from "A23"**.

The same for the second part of the formula, but the second parameter is 1`6`, which means **the sixth column: "F"**.

The rest of the code should now be easily understood, I think...

Comment: I just checked and it is the answer - works with the calculations too. Thank you so much. I couldn't find any similar use of ADDRESS function whole day.